# Extract attachments from EML files

Tags: python-3.x

I currently use this code to Extract attachments from EML files. And I wanted to know if I can link the attachment to mail (EML file). That is, add the eml file name as the attachment name prefix.
So I can know the attachment belongs to what mail.
Thank You

```
import os, re
import email
import argparse
import olefile

def extractAttachment(msg, eml_files, output_path):
    #print len(msg.get_payload())
    #print msg.get_payload()
    if len(msg.get_payload()) > 2:
        if isinstance(msg.get_payload(), str):
            try:
                extractOLEFormat(eml_files, output_path)
            except IOError:
                #print 'Could not process %s. Try manual extraction.' % (eml_files)
                #print '\tHeader of file: %s\n' % (msg.get_payload()[:8])
                pass

        elif isinstance(msg.get_payload(), list):
            count = 0
            while count < len(msg.get_payload()):
                payload = msg.get_payload()[count]
                #récupérer les pièces jointes 
                filename = payload.get_filename()
                #os.rename(filename,'rrrrr'+filename)
                #filename=os.path.join(str(filename), str(eml_files))
                if filename is not None:
                    try:
                        magic = payload.get_payload(decode=True)[:4]
                    except TypeError:
                        magic = "None"                    
                    # Print the magic deader and the filename for reference.
                    printIT(eml_files, magic, filename)
                    # Write the payload out.
                    writeFile(filename, payload, output_path)
                count += 1

    elif len(msg.get_payload()) == 2:
        payload = msg.get_payload()[1]
        filename = payload.get_filename()
        try:
            magic = payload.get_payload(decode=True)[:4]
        except TypeError:
            magic = "None"
        # Print the magic deader and the filename for reference.
        printIT(eml_files, magic, filename)
        # Write the payload out.
        writeFile(filename, payload, output_path)        

    elif len(msg.get_payload()) == 1:
        attachment = msg.get_payload()[0]
        payload = attachment.get_payload()[1]
        filename = attachment.get_payload()[1].get_filename()
        try:
            magic = payload.get_payload(decode=True)[:4]
        except TypeError:
            magic = "None"        
        # Print the magic deader and the filename for reference.
        printIT(eml_files, magic, filename)
        # Write the payload out.
        writeFile(filename, payload, output_path)
    #else:
    #    print 'Could not process %s\t%s' % (eml_files, len(msg.get_payload()))

def extractOLEFormat(eml_files, output_path):
    data = '__substg1.0_37010102'
    filename = olefile.OleFileIO(eml_files)
    msg = olefile.OleFileIO(eml_files)
    attachmentDirs = []
    for directories in msg.listdir():
        if directories[0].startswith('__attach') and directories[0] not in attachmentDirs:
            attachmentDirs.append(directories[0])

    for dir in attachmentDirs:
        filename = [dir, data]
        if isinstance(filename, list):
            filenames = "/".join(filename)
            filename = msg.openstream(dir + '/' + '__substg1.0_3707001F').read().replace('\000', '')


            payload = msg.openstream(filenames).read()
            magic = payload[:4]
            # Print the magic deader and the filename for reference.
            printIT(eml_files, magic, filename)
            # Write the payload out.
            writeOLE(filename, payload, output_path)
#filename = str(eml_files)+"--"+str(filename)
def printIT(eml_files, magic, filename):
    filename = str(eml_files)+"--"+str(filename)
    print ('Email Name: %s\n\tMagic: %s\n\tSaved File as: %s\n' % (eml_files, magic, filename))

def writeFile(filename, payload, output_path):

    filename = str(eml_files)+"--"+str(filename)
    try:
        file_location = output_path + filename
        open(os.path.join(file_location), 'wb').write(payload.get_payload(decode=True))
    except (TypeError, IOError):
        pass

def writeOLE(filename, payload, output_path):
    open(os.path.join(output_path + filename), 'wb')
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Attempt to parse the attachment from EML messages.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--path',default='C:\\Users\\hamd\\Desktop\\TEX\\emails' ,help='eml')#Path to EML files
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--out', default='C:\\Users\\hamd\\Desktop\\TEX\\PJ\\eml_files\\',help='pj')#Path to write attachments to.
    args = parser.parse_args()    

    if args.path:
        input_path = args.path
    else:
        print ("You need to specify a path to your EML files.")
        exit(0)

    if args.out:
        output_path = args.out
    else:
        print ("You need to specify a path to write your attachments to.")
        exit(0)

    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
        for file_names in files:
            eml_files = os.path.join(root, file_names)
            msg = email.message_from_file(open(eml_files))
            extractAttachment(msg, eml_files, output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Knowing that the function that writes the filenames is: def writeFile(filename, payload, output_path)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write this as a comment but is was too long. I won't give a full blown solution, but I'll explain the idea.

A possible solution would be to create an hard link to the extracted attachment, giving to the hard link the same name of EML file. You can append an incremental suffix if you have more attachments in the same EML file:

```
whatever.eml    (original email file)
whatever_001.attch    (hard link to first extracted attachment)
whatever_002.attch    (hard link to second extracted attachment)
...
```

This way:

- you are free to move the extracted attachment anywhere else (but in the same disk, because hard links by definition work only on the same disk)
- you can keep a copy of the attachment (the hard link) together with the EML file without consuming disk space
- in case the extracted file is deleted you have a backup copy of the attachment (the hard links) without consuming disk space

In Python you can create an hard link simply with:

```
import os
os.link(existing_target_file, new_link_name)
```